# Print INNER JOIN in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

i trying to print an inner join with php

There is my code (NEW)

```
         <?php
            $eq1 = "SELECT 
            divisiones.id_eq1 AS Equipo_1,
            eq1.name_eq AS Nombre_E1
            
            FROM divisiones
            
            INNER JOIN equipos AS eq1
                ON divisiones.id_eq1 = eq1.id_eq";

          $ejecutar = mysqli_query($conexion, $eq1);
          if ($ejecutar !== false) {
                        while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutar)){
                          $eq1 = $fila['id_eq1'];
                          $name = $fila['name_eq'];
                        
                          echo $eq1;
                          echo $name;
                        }
            } else {
               echo 'error';
            }
        ?>
```

but it returns an error

> Notice: Undefined index: id_eq1
>
> Notice: Undefined index: name_eq

I do not know if I'm doing it right, if you can help me I'll thank you

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not know what you mean, since I've tried everything

Comment: It looks like there is a syntax error in the SQL. Check the comma before "FROM divisiones".

Comment: Thanks, now return an error in index, (id_eq1 and name_eq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra `,` in your selected return columns. That's why your query fails and returns false.

**Change:**

```
$eq1 = "SELECT 
            divisiones.id_eq1 AS Equipo_1,
            eq1.name_eq AS Nombre_E1,

            FROM divisiones

            INNER JOIN equipos AS eq1
                ON divisiones.id_eq1 = eq1.id_eq";
```

***To:***

```
$eq1 = "SELECT 
            divisiones.id_eq1 AS Equipo_1,
            eq1.name_eq AS Nombre_E1

            FROM divisiones

            INNER JOIN equipos AS eq1
                ON divisiones.id_eq1 = eq1.id_eq";
```

Array Index keys have  to be updated to reflect change.

**From:**

```
  $eq1 = $fila['id_eq1'];
  $name = $fila['name_eq'];
```

**To:**

```
  $eq1 = $fila['Equipo_1'];
  $name = $fila['Nombre_E1'];
```

Comment: Thanks ! now return me " Undefined index id_eq1 and name_eq"

Comment: Updated the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the result of `mysqli_query()`.

For example:

```
 $ejecutar = mysqli_query($conexion, $eq1);
  if ($ejecutar !== false) {
                while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutar)){
                  $eq1 = $fila['id_eq1'];
                  $name = $fila['name_eq'];

                  echo $eq1;
                  echo $name;
                }
    } else {
       //check mysqli_error()
       echo 'error';
    }
```

Comment: Hi, i check this but print me "error"... but the query works in mysql workbench

Comment: Check your sql.  "select" clause has extra comma

Answer (score 0):

These warning messages implies that you are not getting the result in "$ejecutar".
That means your query was not working.
There may be some issue with your connection variable, check it again.

For testing, you can print the $ejecutar directly as :

```
print_r($ejecutar);
```

This will return the object result if it does not return an object than either your query is not running or query is wrongly typed.
To further check the query you can directly run the query on mysqli server.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace

```
  $eq1 = $fila['id_eq1'];
  $name = $fila['name_eq'];
```

To

```
  $eq1 = $fila['Equipo_1'];
  $name = $fila['Nombre_E1'];
```