# Is there a way to fetch subcategory with selecting two databases

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been working on a system to create/fetch data from my categories & subcategories databases.

**My Category Database**

| id | category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Life |
| 2 | Health |

**My Subcategory Database**

| id | parent_id | right |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Friends |
| 2 | 1 | Family |
| 3 | 2 | sleep |

To fetch my category list I did the following code line:

```
<?php foreach ($topics as $key => $topic): /*$topic = All my data from the category table*/ ?>
<td><?php echo $topic['category']; ?> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Now the plan was to fetch my subcategories. What I have been expected to do is to select the parent_id from the subcategory and compare it with the id from the category database and fetch the results with foreach. I tried to implement my idea but it did not work since I had no idea on how to compare those two database. That is why I was searching online, however I didn't come across a solution for my specific problem.

Comment: uhh, `database`? surely you meant `table`s? you can use [`join`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) or do 2 queries with the first one retrieve the categories and the 2nd query to get the sub categories.

Comment: Yes, my bad! It wouldn't be a problem for me to make two queries, but the problem I have is comparing the data. I want to make it like that <?php foreach ($subtopic_with_the_same_id_like_the_above as $key => $topic) so I can display the subcategories

Comment: Why are those two tables to begin with? It should be one, and categories that are on the top level then would simply have their parent_id set to NULL.

Comment: Alright thanks for the help @CBroe, I am going to change it

Answer (score 0):

Use Inner Join

```
SELECT c.name, s.right FROM category as c INNER JOIN subcategory as s ON s.parent_id = c.id
```

This is going to select **Name** (from Category table) and **right**(from subcategory table), where the id of the 2 tables are same. I used `as` keywords to give a name. But you can name it however you want.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for helping out! Short question though -> what does c. and s mean? And if I will implement this code, what exactly will it output me?

Comment: It is temorary name inside SQL (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp). Probably array is going to be returned, so you can loop it. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49647381/print-inner-join-in-php